# Download an Excel file from web server folder

Tags: php, excel, download, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to get Oracle SQL query results to an .xlsx file. I wrote my PHP code in `node--18769.tpl.php` and `node--18769.tpl.xlsx` file is downloading to webroot (/root/themes/bartik/templates) folder with result.

My requirement:

1. Can I rename `node--18769.tpl.xlsx` to `report.xlsx`?
2. Is it possible to prepend `UNIX TIMESTAMP` to file name? (like 1442223364_report.xlsx)
3. How can I download  `report.xlsx` to my local system once after the file is generated?

This is my code:

`require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    // Set document properties
    // Add some data
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
    //print $query; exit;
    $res = db_query($query);
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ( $dataFetched = $res->fetchAssoc() ) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['title'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['tot'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['per']);
        $rowNumber++;
    }
    // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(8)->setRowHeight(-1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Page & Files Reports ');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A8',"Hello\nWorld");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(8)->setRowHeight(-1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));`

Code updated:

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

tells PHPExcel what filename to use when you save the file.... simply change it to

```
$objWriter->save("WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL_THE_FILE.xlsx);
```

If you want to download the file to local, then save to `php://output` and send the appropriate headers to the browser, exactly as described in [the documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser) and shown in [the examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php) provided with PHPExcel

Comment: Thanks Mark. I updated my code. But the `xlsx` file downloaded is corrupted.

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM header at the top of the file, or any plaintext PHP messages in the binary stream of the file

Comment: It contains the html source of web page.

Comment: Then suppress output of that page content if you've called to export as Excel

Answer (score 0):

```
// write the file
$objWriter->save('Excel_report/'filename');

//Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Contact.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: Please add description